# How to create a value of XElement in XSLT with concatenetion of strings

Tags: xml, xslt

I have to create XElement in XSLT by concatenating 
"ORDER"+ DateTimeWithMilliSeconds + OrderNumber.

Not sure how to use string-join or string-concat with xslt

```
<xsl:element name="TransID">
  <xsl:value-of select="fn:concat('ORDER','OrderNumber')"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Please help me with this.I am creating this xslt. Expected output is

```
<TransID>ORDER2015-12-22T11:32:01.2387192-05:00123567</TransID>
```

Comment: Please show a small example of the input and the expected result.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Do you want to take the dateTime from some XML input data? Or do you want to insert the current dateTime?

Comment: @rajalakshmi **Please show a small example of the input.** [2]

Comment: @MartinHonnen : just insert datetime

Comment: @michael.hor257k : there is no input...we are creating new xslt

Comment: If there is no input, where does `OrderNumber` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a concatenate function at all. Just output the various elements one at a time and they will be concatenated on output. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template name="main">
        <out>
             <xsl:variable name="foo">foo</xsl:variable>
             <xsl:variable name="bar">bar</xsl:variable>
             <xsl:value-of select="$foo"/>
             <xsl:value-of select="$bar"/>
        </out>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><out>foobar</out>
```